# Pushing to a view on didReceiveRemoteNotification

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, iphone-sdk-3.0, ios4, push-notification

When the iPhone application is running in background and it receive a remote notification. So it will execute the `didReceiveRemoteNotification` call back. In that I am going to push to a new `UIViewController`. But before that its noticed that its calling the `applicationWillEnterForeground` callback.

In that I am also doing some location update using a modal dialog. So when this notification arrives this both scenarios happens and the app is getting crashed. So is there any way to block the `applictiaonWillEnterBackground` processing on remote notification. As the moment is little bit hard cos this processing is done after `applicationWillEnterBackground` controller.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The callback `application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:` should only be invoked when the application is running in the foreground. When running in the background you should instead get a call to `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`.

Since you are asking the question and also using core location it might be that `application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:` is called when the application is in the background but I would think that would be a bug. At least according to Apple's documentation.

Anyway, NO, you can't block `applicationWillEnterForeground:`. Without knowing exactly what you are doing in the different callbacks I would recommend that you set a flag in `applicationWillEnterForeground:` if you are doing something there and then check that flag in `application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:`

```
- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application {
  if (somehingHappend) {
    somethingHappended = YES;
  }
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo {
  if (!somethingHappened) {
    // push your view controllers or whatever
  }
}
```

*Where `somethingHappened` is a `BOOL` defined in the same class as an ivar.*

Comment: Thanks for your reply Robert. Actually what happens is when a push notification is receive an alert messages is displayed. When I click on the view button of the alert message it will trigger applicationWillEnterForeground after that didReceiveRemoteNotification. So if its was like otherway around I would have used the boolean flag. However if its running in the background will it call the didFinishLaunchingWithOptions when cliking on the view button?

Comment: Yes, that is what should happen. I have only tried it with local notifications myself but `application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:` should, according to the docs, only be called if the application is in the foreground.

Comment: Yes this happens because the app is running in multitasking. So didReceiveRemoteNotification will be called.